# add_trace: control the linetype without warning

Tags: r, plotly

I am writing a function which returns a plotly object. I managed to control the colors already. However I have trouble controlling the linetype. Currently I use something like:

```
plot_ly(colors=c(rep(c("#CD0C18","#1660A7"),each=3),'#9467bd'),linetypes = c(rep(c("dot","dash","solid"),2),"dot")) %>% 
  add_trace(data=long_data,x=~month,y=~temperature,color=~measure,linetype=~measure,type="scatter",mode="lines",line=list(width=4)) %>%
  layout(title = "Average High and Low Temperatures in New York",
         xaxis = list(title = "Months", categoryorder="array", categoryarray=month),
         yaxis = list (title = "Temperature (degrees F)"))
```

which returns me a warning:

> Warning message:
>
> plotly.js only supports 6 different linetypes

The warning makes sense, since `measure` has seven levels. *However I would like to control the `linetype` without getting a warning every time I have more than 6 traces to plot - is there a way?*

My sample data:

```
month <- c('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July',
           'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
high_2000 <- c(32.5, 37.6, 49.9, 53.0, 69.1, 75.4, 76.5, 76.6, 70.7, 60.6, 45.1, 29.3)
low_2000 <- c(13.8, 22.3, 32.5, 37.2, 49.9, 56.1, 57.7, 58.3, 51.2, 42.8, 31.6, 15.9)
mid_2000 <-apply(rbind(high_2000,low_2000),2,mean)
high_2007 <- c(36.5, 26.6, 43.6, 52.3, 71.5, 81.4, 80.5, 82.2, 76.0, 67.3, 46.1, 35.0)
low_2007 <- c(23.6, 14.0, 27.0, 36.8, 47.6, 57.7, 58.9, 61.2, 53.3, 48.5, 31.0, 23.6)
high_2014 <- c(28.8, 28.5, 37.0, 56.8, 69.7, 79.7, 78.5, 77.8, 74.1, 62.6, 45.3, 39.9)
low_2014 <- c(12.7, 14.3, 18.6, 35.5, 49.9, 58.0, 60.0, 58.6, 51.7, 45.2, 32.2, 29.1)

data <- data.frame(month, high_2000, low_2000,mid_2000, high_2007, low_2007, high_2014, low_2014)

long_data<-tidyr::gather(data,measure,temperature,-month)
```

Comment: I want a solution using `plotly`. I know I can get this from `ggplot2`.

Comment: Did you try `suppressWarnings`?

Comment: Nah. I want to use this in a function. Therefore suppressing the warning cripples the function - I mean if I set e.g. the grid-value to "dashed", I want to receive a warning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/plotly_build.R), the warning arises in

```
validLinetypes <- as.character(Schema$traces$scatter$attributes$line$dash$values)
if (length(pal) > length(validLinetypes)) {
  warning("plotly.js only supports 6 different linetypes", call. = FALSE)
}
```

So, if you want to disable this warning alone, there are only two things you can do: override the whole function or manually extend `Schema$traces$scatter$attributes$line$dash$values`. The latter is somewhat less intrusive and can be done with

```
tmp <- plotly:::Schema
tmp$traces$scatter$attributes$line$dash$values <- c(tmp$traces$scatter$attributes$line$dash$values, rep(NA, 100))
assignInNamespace("Schema", tmp, ns = "plotly")
```

Here we add `NA` 100 times so that up to 106 line types now wouldn't provoke a warning. The last line overrides the `Schema` variable with `tmp` in the `plotly` package environment.

The vector `Schema$traces$scatter$attributes$line$dash$values` only gets used (through `validLinetypes`) [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/plotly_build.R) four times, and looking at those it seems like this cheating doesn't have any likely side effects.

Comment: @5th, did that help?

Comment: yes it solved the issue. I decided to make one version where I go around this problem and another where I use your solution.